# Only allow EC2 instance to access static website on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a static website hosted on S3, I have set all files to be public. 
Also, I have an EC2 instance with nginx that acts as a reverse proxy and can access the static website, so S3 plays the role of the origin.

What I would like to do now is set all files on S3 to be private, so that the website can only be accessed by traffic coming from the nginx (EC2).

So far I have tried the following. I have created and attached a new policy role to the EC2 instance with

Policies Granting Permission: AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

And have rebooted the EC2 instance.

I then created a policy in my S3 bucket console > Permissions > Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "xxxxx",
    "Id": "xxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/MyROLE"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

As principal I have set the ARN I got when I created the role for the EC2 instance.

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/MyROLE"
            },
```

However, this does not work, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the Amazon EC2 instance with nginx is merely making generic web requests to Amazon S3, then the question becomes how to identify requests coming from nginx as 'permitted', while rejecting all other requests.

One method is to use a **VPC Endpoint for S3**, which allows direct communication from a VPC to Amazon S3 (rather than going out an Internet Gateway).

A **bucket policy** can then restrict access to the bucket such that it can only be accessed via that endpoint.

Here is a bucket policy from [Example Bucket Policies for VPC Endpoints for Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html):

> The following is an example of an S3 bucket policy that allows access to a specific bucket, `examplebucket`, only from the VPC endpoint with the ID `vpce-1a2b3c4d`. The policy uses the `aws:sourceVpce` condition key to restrict access to the specified VPC endpoint.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

So, the complete design would be:

- Object ACL: Private only (remove any current public permissions)
- Bucket Policy: As above
- IAM Role: Not needed
- Route Table configured for VPC Endpoint

Comment: Seems legit.  I've not tested interaction between VPC endpoints and the web site hosting endpoints, assuming that's what's being used, but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions in Amazon S3 can be granted in several ways:

- Directly on an **object** (known as an Access Control List or ACL)
- Via a **Bucket Policy** (which applies to the whole bucket, or a directory)
- To an **IAM User/Group/Role**

If any of the above grant access, then the object can be accessed publicly.

Your scenario requires the following configuration:

- The ACL on each object should **not** permit public access
- There should be **no Bucket Policy**
- You should assign permissions in the Policy attached to the **IAM Role**

Whenever you have permissions relating to a User/Group/Role, it is better to assign the permission in **IAM** rather than on the Bucket. Use Bucket Policies for general access to *all users*.

The policy on the Role would be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowBucketAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is directly applied to the IAM Role, so there is no need for a `principal` field.

Please note that this policy only allows `GetObject` -- it does not permit listing of buckets, uploading objects, etc.

You also mention that "I have set all files to be public". If you did this by making each individual object publicly readable, then anyone will still be able to access the objects. There are two ways to prevent this -- either remove the permissions from each object, or create a Bucket Policy with a Deny statement that stops access, but still permits the Role to get access.

That's starting to get a bit tricky and hard to maintain, so I'd recommend removing the permissions from each object. This can be done via the management console by editing the permissions on each object, or by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with a command like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket s3://my-bucket --recursive --acl private
```

This copies the files in-place but changes the access settings.

(I'm not 100% sure whether to use `--acl private` or `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`, so play around a bit.)

Comment: The problem with this is that the [static website endpoints do not support IAM authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html).  They do, however, respect other aspects of the bucket policy, so the solution is to upload objects as private, assign an EIP to the instance, and then allow access from that IP in the bucket policy: `"Condition": { "IpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": [ "203.0.113.200/32" ] } }` (assuming EIP is 203.0.113.200). This works as expected as long as you're not using an S3 VPC Endpoint (which doesn't support the `aws:SourceIp` condition).

Comment: Also, it seems like OP may be expecting the IAM role on the instance to allow Nginx to magically be able to fetch objects from the bucket by simple virtue of the fact that Nginx is running on an instance with an IAM role, overlooking the fact that you'd still need to fetch the temporary credentials from instance metadata and use them to sign and authenticate the requests... which would work with the REST endpoint, but not the website endpoint.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I didn't take into consideration how the Amazon EC2 instance was fetching the data from Amazon S3. My above recommendation only works if it is fetching via API requests, but not if it is merely making web requests.

Comment: Thank you both John Rotenstein and @Michael-sqlbot I guess I was naive enough to assume that an EC2 instance will have unrestricted access to S3 and any web requests from it to S3 won't need any authentication. Yes the idea is that all assets are private so that the only way to access them should be through the EC2 instance. Am I right to assume that I am in the right path and that I am missing decorating the requests originating from nginx with amazon authentication headers?

Comment: Using John's other answer or my approach, in comments (which I can expand into a full answer, if desired -- I'm using that strategy behind HAProxy), you should be able to avoid signing the requests by using a different mechanism of trust... but yes, using an instance role as you originally planned requires signing the requests using the temporary credentials from the instance role, which are [easy enough to get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials) but they expire periodically and you have to re-fetch. Messy.